# Submit a search form as "URL/value" without query string "?q=value"

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit, query-string

I have a simple image search form that open in a new window:

HTML

```
<input type="radio" id="google" name="image" onclick="googleImages();" checked/>
<label for="google">Google Images</label>

<input type="radio" id="unsplash" name="image" onclick="poly();"/>
<label for="unsplash">Poly</label>


<form id="form" method="GET" action="https://www.google.com/search?q=">
  <input id="input" type="text" name="q" value="" required>
  <input id="button"  type="submit" value="Search" onclick="this.form.target='_blank';">
  <input id="helper" type="hidden" name="tbm" value="isch">
</form>
```

JS

```
var
  form = document.getElementById("form"),
  input = document.getElementById("input"),
  button = document.getElementById("button"),
  helper = document.getElementById("helper");

function googleImages() {
  form.action="https://www.google.com/search?q=";
  input.name="q";
  helper.name="tbm";
  helper.value="isch";
}
function poly() {
  form.action="https://poly.google.com/search/";
  input.name="";
  helper.name="";
  helper.value="";
}
```

**Code working [here](http://jsbin.com/cozupocusi/1/edit?html,js,output)**

PROBLEM

When I change to Poly in my search form, query string continue set "?" in URL output, generating an error on search results page.

Google Images use some URL parameters like [google.com/search?q=lion&tbm=isch](https://www.google.com/search?q=lion&tbm=isch) that I can reproduce in the form. However, Poly not use query string (?) or parameters (param=value) they just use the "URL/value" like [poly.google.com/search/lion](https://poly.google.com/search/lion)

QUESTION

How create a function that when I select Poly the query string "?" is removed generating an output "URL/value" on submit? In other words, pass the search term (value) as part of the URL without any query or parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like for the poly you are just navigating to a different url.  You don’t want or need this to be a form submission. Instead of submitting a form call window.location.href=  in the JavaScript.